# Prototype event handler

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I've defined the following HTML elements

```
<span class="toggle-arrow">▼</span>
<span class="toggle-arrow" style="display:none;">▶</span>
```

When I click on one of the elements the visibility of both should be toggled. I tried the following Prototype code:

```
$$('.toggle-arrow').each(function(element) {
    element.observe('click', function() {
        $(element).toggle();
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work. I know everything would be much simpler if I used jQuery, but unfortunately this is not an option:

Comment: I know nothing about prototypejs (I'm used to jQuery ways and methods), but messing around, here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/sh9tj/

Comment: What error do you get? What does not work?

Comment: @Ian, make that an aswer so we can upvote you

Comment: @JohnConde I just wanted to post it as a comment first because I wasn't sure if I was crazy and there was a much better way to do it. I added an answer though :)

Comment: And that's my upvote you see :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of iterating through all arrows in the collection, you can use the **[invoke](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/)** method, to bind the event handlers, as well as toggling them. Here's an example:

```
var arrows = $$('.toggle-arrow');
arrows.invoke("observe", "click", function () {
    arrows.invoke("toggle");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ddMn4/

Comment: Nope, you can just use `arrows = $$('.toggle-arrow').invoke("observe", "click", function(e){ arrows.invoke("toggle"); })`

Comment: @Bergi Ahh I see; thanks for that...honestly had no idea. I was just following what the OP started with. At the same time, is there something like that for `toggle`ing?

Comment: @Bergi Per your edit, maybe you should create an answer; definitely more elegant/correct

Comment: @Esailija Like I said, no idea how it could/should really work, just working off the OP's code. Feel free to suggest anything or make an answer (although Bergi's comment/code seems "best")

Comment: @Ian yeah I don't know either, it was just funny to me how awkward the code looks :P

Comment: @Esailija Definitely looks awkward, I don't know why I assumed it was normal; it's not really intuitive. I should've researched it a little more, but I guess I was just focusing on how to toggle a collection. Silly me

Comment: @Bergi I'd rather show the OP the right way, so create an answer or I'll just update this code

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not quite what you're asking for, but consider something like this:

```
<div class="toggle-arrow-container">
    <span class="toggle-arrow" style="color: pink;">▶</span>
    <span class="toggle-arrow" style="display:none; color: orange;">▶</span>
</div>

document.on('click', '.toggle-arrow-container .toggle-arrow', function(event, el) {
    var buddies = el.up('.toggle-arrow-container').select('.toggle-arrow');
    buddies.invoke('toggle');
});
```

This will allow you to have multiple "toggle sets" on the page. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDppd/

Hope this helps on your Prototype adventure.

Answer (score 0):

Off the cuff:

```
function toggleArrows(e) {
  e.stop();

  // first discover clicked arow
  var clickedArrow = e.findElement();

// second hide all arrows
  $$('.toggle-arrow').invoke('hide');

// third find arrow that wasn't clicked
  var arw = $$('.toggle-arrow').find(function(a) {
    return a.identify() != clickedArrow.identify();
  });

// fourth complete the toggle
  if(arw)
     arw.show();

}
```

Wire the toggle arrow function in document loaded event like this

```
document.on('click','.toggle-arrow', toggleArrows.bindAsEventListener());
```

That's it, however you would have more success if you took advantage of two css classes of:  arrow and arrow-selected.  Then you could easily write your selector using these class names to invoke your hide/show "toggle" with something like:

```
function toggleArrows(e) {
    e.stop();

    $$('.toggle-arrow').invoke('hide');
    var arw = $$('.toggle-arrow').reject(function(r) { 
        r.hasClassName('arrow-selected'); });

    $$('.arrow-selected').invoke('removeClassName', 'arrow-selected');

    arw.show();
    arw.addClassName('arrow-selected');

}
```